# Problem with getting values from request using batch

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

I'm new in batch and i need to get a tag from a url like:

`tag_name` in url `https://api.github.com/repos/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest`
So i found that someone was doing this to get it :

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('curl -ks https://api.github.com/repos/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest ^| find "tag_name"') do (
    SET VERSION=%%B
    echo %VERSION%
)
```

But there is two problems :

1. This is getting with loop. isn't there any better way to get it?
2. It returns  `"4.2.4",` Which its extra characters needs to be removed, (Clearly i need to have it like `4.2.4`

Thx to you all.

Comment: `echo %VERSION%` within the parenthesised block will return the *previous* value of the variable unless you use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Or to check the value you could simply use `set VERSION` instead…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a good idea to use tools that understand the language when processing a language. If you are on a supported `windows` system, `powershell.exe` is available, just as much as `findstr.exe` is available.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(& curl.exe -ks https://api.github.com/repos/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest | ConvertFrom-Json).tag_name"
```

To put this into a `batch-file`, you could use:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(& curl.exe -ks https://api.github.com/repos/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest | ConvertFrom-Json).tag_name"') DO (SET "TAG_NAME=%%~A")
ECHO TAG_NAME is set to %TAG_NAME%
```

To use PowerShell commands, you could use:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.github.com/repos/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest).tag_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```sh
@For /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe -ks
 "https://api.github.com/repos/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest" ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "\"tag_name\":" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%%G
```

You could of course use your own code and fix it by reading the usage information for the command you are using. You could do that by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `for /?` and pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. Simply changing your delimiters to include the additional whitespace and comma characters, and modifying your variable expansion to use a tilde, should work for you.